# Why does lists:flatten/2 does not work fine on Erlang script?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to implement the a split method in Erlang that is supposed to split a string like `"i am on the mountain top"` into a list like `["i","am","on","the","mountain","top"]`.

Here is my code (exercise.erl):

```
 -module(exercise).
-import(oi,[read/1]).
-export([split/4]).



split(Text,_,Result,_) when Text == [] -> Result;
split([Head|Tail],Separator,Result,WordSummer) when Head == Separator ->
     split(Tail,Separator,[Result|lists:flatten(WordSummer)],[]);
split([Head|Tail],Separator,Result,WordSummer) -> 
     split(Tail,Separator,Result,[WordSummer|Head]).
```

The problem I'm having is that when calling my exported function I get the following error:

```
9> c(exercise).
{ok,exercise}
10> exercise:split("sdffdgfdg dgdfgfg dgdfg dgdfgd dfgdfgdfgtrty hghfgh",$ ,[],[]).
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:do_flatten(103,[]) (lists.erl, line 627)
     in function  lists:do_flatten/2 (lists.erl, line 628)
     in call from exercise:split/4 (exercise.erl, line 9)
11>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The `[WordSummer|Head]` in the last line is creating an improper list because `Head` is an integer (one character of the input string). This is causing the error you're seeing. You probably meant `[WordSummer, Head]`.
2. `[Result|lists:flatten(WordSummer)]` is creating a nested list instead of a list of strings. To append one item to a list, use `++` and wrap the right side in a list: `Result ++ [lists:flatten(WordSummer)]`

Final code:

```
split(Text,_,Result,_) when Text == [] -> Result;
split([Head|Tail],Separator,Result,WordSummer) when Head == Separator ->
  split(Tail,Separator,Result ++ [lists:flatten(WordSummer)],[]);
split([Head|Tail],Separator,Result,WordSummer) ->
  split(Tail,Separator,Result,[WordSummer, Head]).
```

Test:

```
1> c(exercise).
{ok,exercise}
2> exercise:split("sdffdgfdg dgdfgfg dgdfg dgdfgd dfgdfgdfgtrty hghfgh",$ ,[],[]).
["sdffdgfdg","dgdfgfg","dgdfg","dgdfgd","dfgdfgdfgtrty"]
```

There's still a bug where the last segment is being ignored. I'll let you figure that out (hint: you need to consider `WordSummer` in the first clause of the function).

Comment: Greate Thanks i see that i still need to revise the basics

Comment: please for a sweet-able link where i can do so